# Android - How to exclude PayPal from Email chooser list?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, paypal, android-intent-chooser

I'm using this code to open email chooser via intent

```
val mIntent = Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
        "mailto",
        "name@email.com", null
    )
)
mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "[Feedback - App Name]")
mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "")
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Choose Email Client..."))
} catch (e: Exception) {
    (activity as MainActivity).showToast("There are no email clients installed.")
}
```

it works as expected but it also includes PayPal app in the list of email clients.

[image: email chooser]

On clicking PayPal, if the email is registered with PayPal, it redirects to the payment page. And if not registered, it shows below screen.

[image: paypal]

In both scenarios, there is no option to send emails from the PayPal app.

So, How can I include only email clients in the intent chooser?

I have tried this code as well, it also results in the same.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "addresses")
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject")
if (intent.resolveActivity(activity?.getPackageManager()!!) != null) {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Email Client..."))
}
```

---

EDIT :

I have checked in other apps where the same dialog is opening. May be PayPal app is listening to mail events.

Comment: I have the same problem with paypal

Answer (score 0):

Please look into this :

```
 private void openEmailApp() {
      List<Intent> emailAppLauncherIntents = new ArrayList<>();

      //Intent that only email apps can handle:
      Intent emailAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
      emailAppIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
      emailAppIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
      emailAppIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");

      PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

      //All installed apps that can handle email intent:
      List<ResolveInfo> emailApps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(emailAppIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);

      for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : emailApps) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        Intent launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        emailAppLauncherIntents.add(launchIntent);
      }

      //Create chooser
      Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(new Intent(), "Select email app:");
      chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, emailAppLauncherIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[emailAppLauncherIntents.size()]));
      startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
```

**Edited**

```
private void sendEmail(Connect connect) {
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{connect.getEmail()});
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, getString(R.string.choose_email_client)));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFoundException) {
        UIUtils.showShortSnackBar(fragmentConnectLayout, getString(R.string.no_email_client));
    }
}
```

Comment: same code I have used, also inserted in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the intent package names and remove PayPal. Then create a chooser with your filtered list.

```kotlin
val emailAppLauncherIntents = ArrayList<Intent>()

// Intent that only email apps can handle:
val emailAppIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
emailAppIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")

val packageManager = requireActivity().packageManager

// All installed apps that can handle email intent
val emailApps = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    packageManager.queryIntentActivities(emailAppIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL)
} else {
    packageManager.queryIntentActivities(emailAppIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
}

emailApps.forEach { resolveInfo ->
    val packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
    val launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)

    // Paypal shows up for send intent - we don't want this
    if (!packageName.contains("paypal") && launchIntent != null) {
          emailAppLauncherIntents.add(launchIntent)
    }
}

val chooser = Intent.createChooser(Intent(), getString(R.string.select_email_client))
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, emailAppLauncherIntents.toTypedArray())
startActivity(chooser)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose specific packages to make this action , try this :

```
        val email = "examle@gmail.com"
        val subject = "some text "

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        val data = Uri.parse("mailto:$email?subject=${Uri.encode(subject)}")
        intent.data = data
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm") // Package name for Gmail app
        startActivity(intent)
```